# Python: Removing non-numeric data from CSV

Tags: python, matlab, parsing, csv

I am trying to read CSV files generated by some code I've written on my raspberry pi. Currently, the raspberry pi outputs data with a few lines of warnings or data in the first lines, and then outputs the data stream as numerical values like so:

```
MMA init error = -82        
MMA init error = 0      
MMA init pass    ID = 26    
MMA Sensor Connected    4744    56100
65232   4744    56100
65232   4744    56100
65232   4744    56100
65232   4744    56100
```

I want a way to be able to parse through this and remove all lines with errors and information, so that when I'm running analytics on the numerical data, the other data won't be included. Is there a way to do this, similar to how in MATLAB, you can simply write `filename.data`?

Comment: You could use a regex to only find lines which match `^[\d\s]+$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# coding: utf-8

data =[]
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        fields = line.split('\t')
        if fields[0].isdigit():
            data.append(fields)
```

or use pandas

```
from pandas import read_table
# if you know first row data shows up in 
data = read_table(filename, header=firstrowdata)
```